# Does "He started remembering" breach the laws of english grammar?

Tags: grammaticality, stative-verbs

> He started remembering his past days and got really emotional about it.

vs

> He remembered his past days and got really emotional about it.

Does the 1st sentence breach the laws of English grammar? Because as far as I know, REMEMBER is a state verb and can't be used in continuous form, but I see a lot of these sentences being used in our daily lives.

For instance,

> Believing in god is very important. (isn't believe a state verb?)

and

> After he got to know all the things that she had done for him, he began loving her. (isn't love a stative verb)

Comment: "Past days" is plural, so "about it" should be changed to "about them".

Comment: In English, references to the Christian God are almost always capitalized.

Comment: In your parenthetical notes, "isn't" starts sentences, so it should be changed to "Isn't".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I know, REMEMBER is a state verb and can't be used in continuous form.

It's not that they *can't* be used in continuous form. Refer to the following explanation which is more helpful:

> "Some verbs [believe, doubt, think, remember, ...] are not **usually** used in the continuous form, even when we
>   are talking about temporary situations or states. These are called
>   stative verbs."

[Stative verbs](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/intermediate-grammar/stative-verbs). Emphasis added.

It is unlikely that there is any *grammatical* problem with using the continuous form, but if you do so inappropriately it may feel unnatural:

> ** Are you belieiving in God, Father?

This should likely be recast as:

> Do you believe in God, Father?

However, sometimes using unnatural sounding language is done on purpose and may be appropriate. For example, in 2003 McDonald's chose this slogan:

> I'm lovin' it.

To say *I'm loving something* is unnatural for the same reason that saying *are you belieiving in God* is unnatural. Perhaps the fast food chain chose it because the unnatural sound makes it stand out. Grammar Girl discusses this phrase specifically:

[Grammar Girl - Is "I'm Loving It" Proper Grammar?](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-im-loving-it-proper-grammar)

### -ing not necessarily a continuous action

However, your -ing examples are not exactly to express continuous actions:

> 1. He started remembering his past days and got really emotional about it.

In 1. you are using a verb in combination with another verb: (Subject) (verb 1) (verb 2). Examples:

> Bob **enjoys** **cooking**.
>
> Alice **stops** **working** at five.
>
> I **want** **to believe**.
>
> I'm **writing** **to ask** for your advice.
>
> **Visit** the airline's Web site **to book** a flight.

In this sort of formulation, should the second verb in the pattern use the -ing form (cooking, working), or the to+infinitive form (to ask, to book, to arrange, to believe)? Which one to choose seems to depend on the verb. This is discussed in the following article:

[Cambridge Dictionary - Verb patterns: verb + infinitive or verb + -ing?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing)

However, I would treat the advice in the Cambridge article as guidelines, not as grammatical rules. Cambridge's list of verbs also seems quite incomplete to me. And some verbs in their "-ing" list or their "-to+infinitive" list seem like they could go either way to me:

> I don't **like** **to cook** in the evening.

Although the article would suggest that you should recast as

> I don't **like** **cooking** in the evening.

Is this better? Maybe. But I don't think there's anything wrong with saying *I don't like to cook*, either. You may also find cases where Cambridge's suggested form (e.g., cooking) may yield examples that sound quite wrong:

> ** I want **cooking**.

Do not say this. Instead, say *I want to cook.*

### Seeing is believing

> 2. Believing in god is very important.

In this example, your -ing form is used to make a verb (believe) into a noun phrase. You can see this by substitution:

> 2. [Belief] in god is very important.

Some verbs have natural noun counterparts (believe and belief, see and sight, ...), but most do not. In general a verb can be made into a noun phrase by using the -ing form or by using the to+infinitive form. Doing so effectively 'nounifies' a verb:

> **Seeing** is belieiving.
>
> **Cooking** for beginners.
>
> **To go** the extra mile.
>
> **To** boldly **go** where no man has gone before.
>
> **To Kill** a Mockingbird.

To decide which form to choose, you might consult the Cambridge article again for guidelines, but in many cases the choice may be a matter of taste. For example, Harper Lee could have decided to title her 1960 novel *Killing a Mockingbird* instead, and the famous Star Trek phrase could have been rendered as *Boldly going where no man has gone before*. Those alternatives would have changed how the phrases *feel*, but grammatically I don't see any problem. For example, if I saw a book titled *Killing a Mockingbird*, I would not think it is ungrammatical. *Killing* in this case seems to feel more brutal and violent, whereas *to kill* seems to feel a bit more neutral and clear-headed.

> **To see** is to believe.
>
> ** **To cook** for beginners.
>
> **Going** the extra mile.

*To see* and *going* sound fine, but choosing *to cook* for the last example sounds odd, perhaps because it is likely to be confusing: Is it a book about cooking where you cook for beginners? *Cooking for beginners* might also be misinterpreted in that way, but using *cooking* seems to make the intended meaning clearer: It is a book about cooking and the book is for beginners.

> **Cooking** in the evening is great.
>
> **To cook** in the evening is great.

In this case, confusion seems very unlikely, so either formulation seems plausible to me. Although *cooking* may be preferred, if we follow the guidelines from the Cambrige article. Finally, the position of the word or the phrase used may also dictate which form you choose:

> A beginner's guide to **cooking**.

Probably because the word *to* already appears directly before the action, it is very unlikely that you would choose the to+infinitive form in this case. This would the case no matter what you tried to substitute for *cooking* (agreeing, arranging, seeing, eating, ...).