# Reminiscing about (someone / something) - A casual alternative

Tags: word-usage, word-request, idioms, expressions

I wonder what do you usually say when you recall pleasant past memories about someone?

The only word I know is ["reminisce"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/reminisce) which sounds formal for everyday speech.

**Example:**

> I'm **reminiscing** about Cindy and her laughters. Haha! 
> Yea, those were the good old days.

**Another example:**

> I'm **reminiscing** about that vacation we took to Amsterdam.

Could you please tell me whether there is a better verb or expression and on the whole, a more casual way fitting better in everyday speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay if it's not the word you're looking for, but "reminiscing" is not too formal for everyday speech (at least, not mine!). It's a great choice because it has exactly the meaning you're looking for—dwelling on memories of the past, with a specifically positive connotation.

Some other good options would be to use broader words:

> I'm **thinking** about that vacation...

> I'm **remembering** that vacation...

(By the way, if there's any confusion, see [these](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182931/does-he-started-remembering-breach-the-laws-of-english-grammar) [questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/301650/can-we-use-the-verb-remember-in-progressive-tense) about "remembering" in the continuous tense.)

You can also add modifying words:

> I'm **thinking fondly of** that vacation...

There are number of idioms about reminiscence, but they might sound even more contrived:

> I'm just **taking a walk down memory lane**... [this one doesn't take an object, so you still would have to pair it with an explanation like "by remembering that vacation"]

> I'm **reliving the memory of** that vacation...